New HNQ update: What kind of questions do set a good example for our site?
As requested, this is the sister thread to New HNQ update: What kind of questions don't set a good example for our site?. See the linked post for context.
HNQ is the acronym for Hot Network Questions, which commonly appear on the right hand side side menu.
Purpose of this post
This post is concerned with suggestions for what kinds of questions the crypto.stackexchange community does approve as hot network questions.
Keep in mind
The update does not create an ability for moderators to say "This is now a hot network question". 
It only provides the ability for moderators to say "This is not/will not be a hot network question".
Consequently, questions that fit the format of suggestions here are not guaranteed to become hot network questions. They still have to earn their way to that position via the usual means.
Why discuss this then?
Answering the question of "what should be eligible" can be helpful to learn "what should not be eligible", which is the question that we actually need answers to. 

High-level questions about cryptography of some practical significance to a broad audience, particularly those that are in the news already, and to which there are clear technical answers.  Examples:

How is the Swiss post e-voting system supposed to work, and how was it wrong?
Is the software that uses PGP broken, or is it PGP itself?
How does the ROCA attack work?
What is “Fast Prime”?
Do recent announcements about solving the DLP in $GF(2^{6120})$ apply to schemes proposed for cryptographic use?
Applicability of IBM's projected 50-qubit quantum computer Q to cryptanalysis?
What is the new attack on SHA-1 "SHAttered" and how does it work?


Any question about the specifics of a particular well known algorithm or protocol would be welcomed at HNQ. For instance, questions about specifics of SHA-2 or AES or TLS could be interesting to a wider audience. Even though those may not be the most interesting in an academic sense, it may still attract more interest for our site.

like :https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10493/why-is-tls-susceptible-to-protocol-downgrade-attacks
